# Registration system using ion auth in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, ion-auth

I have developed a registration form using codeigniter framework which works fine. But now I want to integrate it with ion auth library to make it more scalable. But I am new to using external libraries in codeigniter and I don't know how to use ion auth to build a registration system. Can any one please let me know some good tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

first of all have you read the [official documentation](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#install) which includes a detailed installation procedure ?

Also I think Ion Auth doesnt provide templates (views ) for handling registration,etc

Also have you considered using tank auth ?
Tank auth provides some basic views which handles registration, login etc.

Edit :
have a look at the views provided [here](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/tree/master/views/auth)

Comment: Can you give a demo of simple registration form using ion auth?

Comment: @Sanks R - Ion Auth provides views for registration. Check out the "create_user.php" file.